# Is my code prone to sql-injection?

Tags: php, sql

Is my code prone to sql-injections? and why? I would like to know what to change in order to be "safe"

```
  @$con = mysql_connect($host,$dbuser,$dbpass);

if (!$con)

{

    echo "Failed to connect: " . mysql_error();

}


    @mysql_select_db($dbname,$con) or die ( "Unable to connect $dbname");
```

Comment: Since you're using the deprecated `mysql-*` API, I'd say you're at bigger risk than with more modern APIs (mysqli or PDO). You're not showing any SQL code though, so hard to tell for sure.

Comment: As the poster above said, change from mysql_* to PDO or Mysqli, and use parameterized queries (instead of adding variables directly to the query you add placeholders like ? or :placeholdername)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, where can I read about the technique I'm currently using, is it called mysql-* ?

Comment: @multibajz you don't really have to - it's not even available any more in the latest version of PHP. Just drop it and move on :)